# VS Studio 2008 VB.Net Winform - can it be run on a MAC?

Tags: winforms, macos

Our company has a handful of Mac users.  I recently built a Winform application and now my main user is using a Mac.  Is it possible to run this application on a Mac?  What would have to be done to convert it?  If it is too much, I may just rebuild it is asp.net as a web application.

Thanks in advance!

JCC

Comment: I know this doesn't relate to your question, but you could always host the app on a windows server box and allow the mac users to RDP to the box and use it there...

Comment: How is your main user using it on a mac?  It could run on a windows virtual machine on the mac.  Is that what he does now.  If so...sorry for the non-answer.
Seth

Answer (score 4):

Maybe. Many .Net programs can be compiled with mono as well, winforms usually is not a problem, but some libraries (e. g. MS Office libraries for editing Excel files). I am not sure about VB, as mono coders mostly use C#, but you can analyse your code with the [Mono Migration Analyzer](http://mono-project.com/Moma) for portability to mono.

Comment: Good tip about the migration analyzer: +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending a bit on features and controls used, it may run on [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page). Since you can run Mono on Windows as well it's rather easy to download and test it.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic options are (from least intrusive to most intrusive, from the point of view of a Mac user):

1. Convert it to a web app.
2. Run it on a Terminal Server and have them use Remote Desktop.
3. Run the application in a virtual machine (VMWare or Parallels) that is running Windows.
4. Try to get it running under Mono.

If there isn’t a strong reason for it to be a desktop application, you really should be thinking in terms of web apps for new applications—at least, that’s an unwritten rule where I work.